# Jquery function to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have functlion which is working perfactly. Now the client’s requirement is that he doesn’t want to use any other file for js, so I have change this function to be pure JavaScript, i.e. without jQuery. I am confused where to start.

Can you guys tell me a JavaScript function similar to jQuery’s `.size` method?

http://jsfiddle.net/CgDS6/8/

```
    <div class="wrap">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="first">
                    <div class="second"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="first">
                    <div class="active"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="first">
                    <div class="second"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
    </div>

var $firstSecond = $('.second').eq(0);
$('#next').click(function() {
    var $active = $('.active');
    var $nextSecond = $active.closest('li').next().find('.second');
    $active.toggleClass('active second');
    if ($nextSecond.size() != 0) {
        $nextSecond.toggleClass('second active');
    } else {
        $firstSecond.toggleClass('second active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Before people start with the *"jQuery is JavaScript!"* comments, I'm certain OP means jQuery API to DOM API.

Comment: What browsers are being supported?

Comment: My inclination is to tell you to copy the minified jQuery source into the same JS file.

Comment: Is the client technical? Why does she care about using libraries?

Comment: It kills me when people prefix all their JS variables with `$` signs...

Comment: @SamDufel it's a useful naming convention for identifying which variables refer to jQuery objects.

Comment: @SamDufel, I prefix jQuery collections with `$` to distinguish them from my standard objects. It looks like the same is being done here.

Comment: i dont why she want me to do this with javascript but i have to do i cant aregu with the client

Comment: @Rocket: sure, although this chap’s used the `$` prefix for a DOM element too: `var $firstSecond = $('.second').eq(0);`. Wait, does `$().eq` return a DOM element? I may have made a fool out of myself.

Comment: Upvoted all the comments about prefixing jQuery objects with `$`, but it really bothers me when people miss the point of this and prefix everything with `$`... so im kinda with @SamDufel

Comment: There's nothing difficult to translate in the code above. Is somebody already doing it in a didactic way (I don't feel like doing it) ?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite `.eq()` does not return a bare DOM element. http://api.jquery.com/eq/ ...but boy, are we **way** off-topic.

Comment: Alright, this has become too chatty. Enough is enough.

Comment: Can we please stop with the off topic discussion about variable naming. It makes it difficult to communicate with OP about the issue at hand.

Comment: what is the similer to .size in javaScript

Comment: @amit: `.length` (which works in jQuery too).

Comment: @amit, `var collection = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); collection.length`

Comment: and what about the .next, what is alternative of .next in javaScript

Comment: @amit: This is going to be a little too tedious. If you're going to be a software developer for hire, you need to learn the language and the API. If you have an over dependence on jQuery, then that's going to be a problem in general.

Comment: Why is hungarian notation suddenly cool when it comes to jQuery? Do you prefix your variables with `s` `b` etc too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported in IE6+.  You could also do this with event handlers, but I didn't want to implement a cross-browser event handler and decided to do this quick and dirty with `onclick`:

```
function getElementsByClassName(cn, rootNode) {
  if (!rootNode) {
    rootNode = document;
  } 
  for (var r=[], e=rootNode.getElementsByTagName('*'), i=e.length; i--;) {
    if ((' '+e[i].className+' ').indexOf(' '+cn+' ')>-1) {
      r.push(e[i]); 
    }
  }
  return r;  
}

document.getElementById('next').onclick = function(){
    var active = getElementsByClassName('active')[0],
        lis = getElementsByClassName('wrap')[0].getElementsByTagName('li'),
        nextSecond;

    for (var i = 0, il = lis.length; i < il; i++) {
        if (getElementsByClassName('active', lis[i]).length) {
            nextSecond = i + 1 < il ?
                         getElementsByClassName('second', lis[i + 1])[0] :
                         getElementsByClassName('second', lis[0])[0]
        }
    }

    active.className = 'second';
    nextSecond.className = 'active';
};
```

### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QGUwc/)

Comment: You might want to use my my `getElementsByClassName` with @rsplak's clean solution.  I don't know of any books to learn this crappy old-way of writing Javascript, I've just been writing it since the crappy old-way was the only way.

Comment: @amit: You can start at [MDN's DOM overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/), but to learn Javascript [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript) is a good entrance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById('next').onclick =  function() {
   var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('second');
   var active = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];

   for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
     if(divs[i]==active) divs[i].className = 'second';
     if(divs[(i)%divs.length] == active) divs[(i+1)%divs.length].className = 'second active';
   }    
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CgDS6/9/)

Comment: @amnotiam what isn't compatible with IE8 (that's a question) ?

Comment: @dystroy: `getElementsByClassName` didn't show up until IE9. :(

Comment: Oh yes... just to help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie

Comment: @am not i am: Ah, didn't think of that. And thanks @ dystroy for adding the link

Comment: With the borrowed getElementsByClassName (that you should include), this seems to me to be the most compatible and above all the clearest answer.

Comment: `.querySelectorAll` can be a nice substitute for IE8 as long as you don't need a "live list"

Comment: but needs quite a shim for IE7 ;D

Comment: @rsplak: Your script does not really do what the OP's one does, regarding the classes. Also note that the if-conditions in your loop are equal and should be merged.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the equivalent for the `size` method **in your specific case** to size a jQuery Object in Javascript is [`length`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp), because jQuery DOM selected objects are arrays.

You can have a look at the [jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) to see what they are doing in javascript to make jQuery work. Command-F will find you all the different commands and all.

If it's just about the size of files the client wants to be reduced, copy the jQuery source code in your file. You could also keep different files in your development environment and copy them all together [and minify them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) for production use, which is a common practice, so you have the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/DQSna/3/

```
var firstSecond = document.querySelector(".second");

document.querySelector("#next").addEventListener("click", function() {


    function toggleClasses( node ) {
        node.classList.toggle("active");
        node.classList.toggle("second");    
    }

    var active = document.querySelectorAll(".active"),
        nextSecond = [].map.call( active, function( node ) {
            while (node && node.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "li") {
                 node = node.parentNode;   
            }
            return node && node.nextElementSibling && node.nextElementSibling.querySelector( ".second" ) || null;
        }).filter(Boolean);

        [].forEach.call( active, toggleClasses );

        if( nextSecond.length ) {
            [].forEach.call( nextSecond, toggleClasses );
        }
        else {
            toggleClasses( firstSecond );
        }
}, false );​
```

Comment: As long as you don't care about IE7

Comment: `.forEach` `.map` and `.filter` will need a shim for IE8.

Comment: Tbh, if the client's requirement is no external js files, would probably be easier just to inline jQuery

Comment: This is very close to what jQuery does, but I'm quite sure we can assume that there is only one `active` and `nextsecond` at a time.

Comment: @Bergi yes it's a blind translation. Mostly to refresh my memory about DOM equivalents

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery in plain DOM-methods (note that most of them will not be supported by IE):

```
var firstSecond = document.querySelector(".second'");
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var active = document.querySelector(".active"),
        nextSecond = active.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector(".second");
    active.classList.remove("active");
    active.classList.add("second");
    (nextSecond || firstSecond).classList.remove("second");
    (nextSecond || firstSecond).classList.add("active");
}, false);
```

Note that this requires that the elements `firstSecond`, `#next` and `active` are always found - if not, you need to add a check for them being not `null`.

Your DOM might be cleaner (and the JS simpler) when you:

- would use `active` as an id, I guess it is unique (which only would make selecting the element easier)
- would set the `li`s themselves as active, I guess that state counts for the whole branch (and therefore allows more styling)
- would not remove the `second` class from the divs - they're still second (*and* active)
- would not use `first` and `second` classes at all - you can select those divs with normal CSS selectors (`li > div` and `li > div > div`)

Comment: the `.toggle` cannot take multiple classes like jQuery. The code is also not the same, where's `closest("li")` etc?

Comment: Ah, that's true. The `closest("li")` was transformed into a single `nextElementSibling` - I thought the `li` itself had the active class. Wait, I'll correct that.

Comment: Yeah I suppose those are the only mistakes as long as it behaves the same