# How to define element without ID?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I have an `element` in `CSS`. I'm using:

```
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered {to add style to it}
```

But in `JS` I need to define it and I don't have and `Id`, the only way to define is `ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered`.

I'm new in `JS`.

Should I use `getElementById`? Or what?

EDIT:

I'm trying to use jquery, but it's first time I use it, I'm trying to change element's (ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered) width to window width on page resize, but it doesn't seem to work :/

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 $("ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered").width()=$(window).width();
});
```

Comment: there is a function getElementsByClassName or if you use jquery.... just type $("ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered")

Comment: *"But in JS I need to define it"* I don't even know what you mean that. Do you want to get a reference to the element? Do you want to create an element? "Defining an element" is not a phrase that is commonly used in this context.

Comment: From all the answers I have a conclusion, that jquery is easier way, I think i'll use it, because I'm green in JS and jquery and it's hard to me to understand what nodelist is and it's also uncompatible with some IE versions.

Comment: Felix Kling, I was unsure of using word 'define' here. English is not my main language. I meant, that I need to  attach element to a variable and I don't know what function do I use to get my element which does'nt have an ID. Hope you understand now.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName("classname")` will return a nodeList. You can loop in it and reach item what you want.

Comment: But getElementsByClassName does not work on IE 5,6,7 and 8 right?

Comment: @Edper, yeah you are right, there is a solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie

Comment: @Quentin - what's the difference between an array and a nodelist? Isn't a nodelist an array?

Comment: @Saturnix — There are a lot of similarities, but the obvious difference is that it will fail if you try to `instanceof foo === Array`

Comment: @Saturnix: No it isn't. E.g. you cannot add elements to a NodeList and it does not have any of the array methods, i.e. `.push`, `.pop`, `.map`, `.slice`, `.forEach`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

You can find the element by using other identified elements or using classes as people mentioned above.

Comment: What makes you think the OP uses jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery like below

```
$(".ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered").html()
```

like that

Comment: What if the OP cannot or doesn't want to use jQuery? From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*