# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

I'm trying to select elements with `.getElementsByTagName()`.

```
var tags = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Current attempt using lessons learned from an existing answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie/7410966#7410966](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7410966/2007055)

But my attempt failed and I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

Why is it producing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does `console.log(document.body)` give you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Move the `<script>` from the `<head>` element to the `<body>` element.

---

`document.body` won't get a value assigned to it until the body element has been created.

Since you are trying to get all the elements in the `<body>`, you'd want to be at the *end* of the body element. Or put it in a function and call it from an event that fires after the body has been created (such as the `window` `load` event). To read more about that try, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event.

Answer (score -1):

Function examples:

- [Page loaded with pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)
- [Page loaded with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Example with both methods:

```
function init() {
  alert("hello javascript");
};

window.addEventListener("load",init,false);

$(document).ready(function () {
  alert("hello jQuery");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5zu4Lt/

Be careful, the JavaScript example above waits for page load (images, iframes, etc.). This takes more time than jQuery's ready.