# Changing a href of an image in the footer area with custom JavaScript, WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have been trying to change the a href of a branding image (in WordPress) located in the footer area with custom JavaScript, I think the image and the URL is defined here:

```
  <!-- !Bottom-bar -->
    <div id="bottom-bar"  role="contentinfo">
        <div class="wf-wrap">
            <div class="wf-container-bottom">
                <div class="wf-table wf-mobile-collapsed">

                    <div id="branding-bottom" class="wf-td"><a href="https://change this url.com/"><img class=" preload-me" src="default.jpg" srcset="default.jpg 240w, default.jpg 240w" width="240" height="60"   sizes="240px" alt="default" /></a></div>
                        <div class="wf-td">
                            <div class="wf-float-left">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I have tried some solutions but nothing seems to work properly.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("branding-bottom").href = "https://www.newpageurl.html";
</script>
```

In other posts, this code was successfully used to change href and the image itself but I can only see this error when I try to load the page.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null at https://change this url.com/:366
```

I am thankful for every help I can get this is still somewhat new and confusing for me. Thank you!

Comment: This post might help you do that link change https://stackoverflow.com/a/179717/8306355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`branding-bottom` is a `<div>` and has no `href`

What you're trying to do is get the child of `branding-bottom`

This should work:

```
document.getElementById("branding-bottom").children[0].href = "https://www.newpageurl.html";
```

```js
document.getElementById("branding-bottom").children[0].href = "https://www.newpageurl.html";
```

```html
<div id="branding-bottom" class="wf-td">
  <a href="https://change this url.com/">link change</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the fast response now my custom JavaScript gives me following error:
`code`
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null at (index):36

Comment: @9jq that means the element with the id was not found. If you change the HTML you need to change the javascript selectors accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are selecting the parent div, but you should rather select the link  in order to access its .href parameter.

Concretely:

```
<div id="branding-bottom" class="wf-td">
    <a id="link-to-change" href="https://change this url.com/"><img class=" preload-me" src="default.jpg" srcset="default.jpg 240w, default.jpg 240w" width="240" height="60"   sizes="240px" alt="default" /></a></div>
    <div class="wf-td">
        <div class="wf-float-left">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then in your script:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("link-to-change").href = "https://www.newpageurl.html";
</script>
```

**Edit:**

In case you get the "cannot select null element" error, check your script is runned once the html has been parsed:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    // Waits for the html to be parsed
    document.getElementById("link-to-change").href="https://www.newpageurl.html";
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, Unfortunately, this returns the same error I had originally, thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Ok so you get every time a null error. Check this: is your script in your .html file ? If yes try this in your js: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    // Waits for the html to be parsed
    document.getElementById("link-to-change").href= "https://www.newpageurl.html";
});  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your item with the id of branding-bottom is a `<div>` and doesn't have an href attribute. The href attribute is on the `<a>` tag that is a child of it. Try

```
document.querySelector('#branding-bottom > a').href = 'https://www.newpageurl.html'
```

Comment: Hello,
Unfortunately, this returns the same error I had originally, thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Just to be sure, is your script being called after the DOM has loaded? And the ID is definitely spelled the same in the script an on the div?

Comment: This should be working based on this codepen, which is what makes me think maybe the script is running before the <div> or the <a> are on the page:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEVodX?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript you are using is incorrect. You need to be targeting the actual `a` element, not it's parent div.

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById("branding-bottom").getElementsByTagName("a")
    element[0].href= "https://www.newpageurl.html"
</script>
```

The code above would first get the `branding-bottom` Id before getting a list of `a` elements inside of that div. From there, we select the first result and assign the URL using the `href` attribute;

There is also an easier way of doing it in jQuery:

```
<script>
    $("#branding-bottom a").attr("href", "https://www.newpageurl.html")
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the fast response now my custom JavaScript gives me following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Comment: @9jq [See these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264313/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-getelementsbytagname-of-null), they may help you fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First a huge thank you for all your help this thing is finally working now. I think you were right the script was running before the DOM.
However, the newer solutions did not change the way the URL was linked. I just did not get an error when inspecting the site. In the end, a mix from 2 suggestions managed to get it working.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    var element = document.getElementById("branding-bottom").getElementsByTagName("a")
    element[0].href= "https://www.google.com"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Glad. Then could you give a point to the answers that helped you please ?

Comment: The solution that worked in the end was a mix of your answers. I posted a short summary of what I did and gave rep to the first person who was asking for it.  Very glad for all your help, thank you.