# How to use javascript innerHTML.split in a class type?

Tags: javascript, html, split, getelementbyid

I'm using google maps for my website.Below code is working with HTML id element, and I need to use it in class elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
    var coords = document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML.split(",");
    var lat = coords[0];
    var lng = coords[1];

    var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

  var myMarkerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myMarkerLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
</script>
```

In the above code I'm using the below code line to get element by ID:

```
var coords = document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML.split(",");
```

But, I want to use this code to work with class elements.

Any solution would be great.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: did you mean get elements with class name?

Comment: you can use jquery to access elements by class `$('.myClass')`

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti yes, I want to use class name to call javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getElementsByClassName(node, classname) {
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('(^| )'+classname+'( |$)');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}

tabs = getElementsByClassName(document.body,'tab');  // no document
```

Check the answer here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie)

Comment: You will be getting the array list of similar match classes and the respective data in the array index value. Take the value and split it.