# getElementById("div").getElementsByClassName("class") is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using this:

```
document.getElementById("div").getElementsByClassName("class");
```

The above seems to work in Chrome and FireFox, but not in IE8.

I am using

```
document.getElementById("branch").getElementsByClassName("branch.address");
```

Above one fetches one row but using this

```
document.getElementById("branch").querySelectorAll("branch.address");
```

fetched empty

How do I make this work in IE8?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/7410949/3166303

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't `getElementById`, it's `getElementsByClassName` — IE8 doesn't have that.

Instead, you can use `querySelectorAll`, which is on all modern browsers, and also IE8:

```
document.getElementById("div").querySelectorAll(".class");
```

Or all in one:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#div .class");
```

`querySelectorAll` accepts any CSS selector, and returns a list of matching elements. There's also `querySelector`, which accepts any CSS selector, and returns the *first* matching element (or `null` if none match).

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support `getElementsByClassName()`. See this [post](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2014/03/get-elements-by-class-name-ie8/) for more details. Also see the link posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie) for a SO post with work-arounds.