# document.getElementsByClassName suddenly no longer working

Tags: javascript

Suddenly I’m experiencing something strange with **document.getElementsByClassName** in my website.

Here is what happened:

I am running an aspx website on IIS7.0 where some parts of my JavaScript code uses **document.getElementsByClassName**.
I never experienced any problems with this on Firefox, Chrome or IE8+

Today, I’m migrating my website to a new server, which runs IIS7.0 as well.

I copied my website, and suddenly **document.getElementsByClassName** is not recognized any more by IE8+ (*it works normally in Chrome and Firefox though...*)

I know there is a workaround for this issue described here: [javascript document.getElementsByClassName compatibility with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie) but that is not the question.

My question is: how is it possible that document.getElementsByClassName no longer works, while I just copied my website?

Is their something to be changed on the new server, IIS, … ?

Many thanks,

Comment: You checked it earlier on IE8?

Comment: I did, it worked on IE8+. Anyway, by example, my old website is still working fine on IE11, but the new one is not on IE11.

Comment: How did you know it was `getElementsByClassName`? Did you check the console? or did you just suspect?

Comment: Hm. Caniuse.com at least, disagrees with your seal of IE8 approval: http://caniuse.com/#search=getelementsby. Anyway, if it's not working on IE11, check what compatibility mode the site is in, using the F12 menu. There are a number of situations where IE11 might automatically try to show the site in IE7 compatibility mode.

Comment: @Katana314 I was in the assumption it worked on IE8. But the question remains, why is the new website not working on e.g. IE11 but the old one does work on IE11

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer console: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: @Mic `Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'`

Comment: There's your problem. `document` may not be what you think it is.

Comment: @Tom have you set the `doctype` property?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer How do you mean? I just copied my website?

Comment: @Tom The major change to this working app is the change of server. I'm pretty sure my comment above is a much more likely cause for the issue than Joseph's prediction of coding mistakes. Sudhansu gave a good suggestion as to the reason Compatibility Mode is being changed, but ultimately, that's the thing you have to check. Read my earlier comment.

Comment: @Katana314 Many thanks. We website was rendering in IE7. I've changed my web.config and now it works

Comment: @Tom Whenever you have IE compatibility issue, please look at "IE Compatibility/Standard mode", to be put straight forward!! Observe the mode in which it is functioning.. javaScript ain't that buggy also to stop supporting their built in functions...!! It's the browser!! Finally that's what decides and renders what it does!!

Answer (score 1):

> The major change to this working app is the change of server. I'm
>   pretty sure my comment above is a much more likely cause for the issue
>   than Joseph's prediction of coding mistakes. Sudhansu gave a good
>   suggestion as to the reason Compatibility Mode is being changed, but
>   ultimately, that's the thing you have to check. Read my earlier
>   comment.

– Katana314

Answer (score 1):

Already suggested in comments, but to wrap up as answer:

If a working IE11 site suddenly stops working on another server, *and the connection string's structure has changed in some way*, the most likely cause is that IE11 believes it's viewing an old intranet site, and pessimistically uses IE7 mode for maximum compatibility. A few other things can cause this, like having an unreadable or old `<!DOCTYPE` at the beginning of the page.

You can change IE11's default compatibility settings to fix the issue locally, use a fully-qualified domain name, or there are some `<meta>` tags or HTTP response headers you can add to change IE's default behavior. Microsoft would likely have more informative articles on their own site.