# Internet Explorer 11 behaves differently on two machines

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, getelementsbyclassname

I'm running IE 11 on my machine. I have a webpage that uses getElementsByClassName. When I access the webpage on my machine the page is served up and it works fine (it executes getElementsByClassName). If I access the same webpage on a different machine also using IE and it can’t find the method getElementsByClassName. If I save the code served up to the browser on the failing machine and access that, the saved page works fine (it executes elemmentsByClassName works). What is going on? How do I tell the browser to use the version of the DOM or javascript that has getElementsByClassName?

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("mrClickableRow");
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie

Comment: Add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge; Chrome=1" />` to `<head>`  of your page. Also consider _degrade gracefully_ like `if(!document.getElementsByClassName)...`

Comment: Depending on how you're using the elements after retrieving them, you might consider using the flexible and backwards-compatible `document.querySelectorAll(".mrClickableRow")`

Comment: Using <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge; Chrome=1" /> did the trick. All machines are working correctly now.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that IE is using the correct Document Mode to render your page, if not, it can simulate and older DOM-API which can cause some problems.

Open your Developer Tools by hitting F12 in IE, or selecting it by the settings-menu. Then go to the Emulation-tab and look at the Document Mode-dropdown.

Comment: While the developer tools are inactive, IE always uses the latest version installed. Or can this be changed somewhere in the settings?

Comment: @Aloso it can vary depending on the compatibility lists, which are specific to a given user profile on a given machine. Any site configured to display in compatibility view will render as if in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` is available from IE 9, are you sure you integrate JS with `<script type="text/javascript">`?

P.S. Use `<script>` before the `</body>` (body closing tag)

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility issues, you can use this function.

```
window.getElementsByClassName = function(node, classname) {
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('(^| )' + classname + '( |$)');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; i++)
        if (re.test(els[i].className)) a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}

if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
        return window.getElementsByClassName(document.body.parentNode, className);
    };
}
```

But be aware that this function and the built-in function are slightly different: When you use the built-in `document.getElementsByClassName` function, it returns an `HTMLCollection`. If you then delete the class of an element contained in the HTMLCollection, it is also removed from the HTMLCollection.