# Javascript code is not working as expected for hiding column

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I have a `Gridview` in which I want to hide a column based on some condition. So for that I have written a js code which is below

```
function GridExpInfo_ClientInsert() {
    var rowVal = GridExpInfo.Rows.length - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < GridExpInfo.Rows.length; i++) {
        if (GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == "" || GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == "0") {
            document.getElementById('GridExpInfo_ob_GridExpInfoBodyContainer_ctl33_'+rowVal+'_ctl00_'+rowVal+'_Button1_'+rowVal+'').style.display = "none";
        } else {                        
        }
    } 
}
```

It works fine, till there is one row added. But if I go to add second row what happens is the first row again gets `show` and the second(current) rows gets `hide`.

So how to hide all the rows whose values consist of `0`

Comment: Because `rowValue` is always the value of the last item in the list, you are effectively looping through, checking the value of each row and always assigning the visibility on the last row item

Comment: @Corporalis: Yes, it takes always the last item. Any other way to crack this logic of getting ID dynamically..

Comment: As you can't use `document.getElementsByClassName`, I'm guessing it's an earlier version of IE. Might be worth checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie) out. Then you could use  the answer @gh9 provided

Comment: @Corporalis: Actually I cracked it by own, anyways thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quite research and trying, I finally cracked this logic. Here is what I did and it worked for me.

```
function GridExpInfo_ClientInsert() {
        var rowVal = "0";                  // assigned variable with value as 0
        for (i = 0; i < GridExpInfo.Rows.length; i++) {                
            rowVal = i;                   // assigning values which always takes the value of i
            if (GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == "" || GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == "0") {
                 document.getElementById('GridExpInfo_ob_GridExpInfoBodyContainer_ctl33_' + rowVal + '_ctl00_' + rowVal + '_Button1_' + rowVal + '').style.display = "none";
             }
            else {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to hide a column in a page that inherits a Master Page from asp.net.  If that is the case ct133 and ct100 names will **100% change as you modify the page**.

You should just assign them a **CSS CLASS** and hide/show every element with that **CSS CLASS**

In vanilla JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName('HideThisColumn')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

with JQUERY

```
 $(".HideThisColumn").hide();
```

***EDIT***
Per OP's comment *My Version is To Low*
According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) IE 9+ has the ability to use this function. Are you stating you are developing against IE 8?

Comment: But, I dont get `document.getElementsByClassName` as my version is low

Comment: What is your version of IE?

Comment: The version which I am using is `IE8`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try to break you code down more simply:

```
(assume obj.rows.length = 5)
clientInsert () {
    var rowVal = (5 - 1) = 4;
    for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
       // first Iteration...
       if ( obj.rows [ 0 ].cells [ 7 ].value == '' ||
            obj.rows [ 0 ].cells [ 7 ].value == "0" ) {
         var id = 'id_' + 4 + 'moreId_' + 4; // 'id_4_moreId_4'
         document.getElementById ( id ) = "none";
       }
       // second Iteration...
       if ( obj.rows [ 1 ].cells [ 7 ].value == '' ||
            obj.rows [ 1 ].cells [ 7 ].value == "0" ) {
         var id = 'id_' + rowVal + 'moreId_' + rowVal;
         // ID is always 'id_4_moreId_4'
         document.getElementById ( id ) = "none";
       }
    }
}
```

So as far as I can see, you're always selecting the same DOM element; your ID never changes.

One thing, getting away from IDs seems to be more "modern". Tagging those target DOM elements with a common CSS style would let you use a straightforward selector and not have to mess around with all that ID stuff. Maybe that doesn't work in your context, but something to consider.