# Problem while trying to use click event in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, click, internet-explorer-11, onclicklistener

I have a code

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('fullscreen-button')[0];
el.click();
```

It works in chrome, firefox but el.click() doesnot work in ie11. (I am getting the expected el in ie11 so getElementsByClassName is working fine in all browsers).

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265315/ie-11-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-getelementsbyclassname

Comment: Is it in any way possible to drop support for IE11? That browser is antiquated, and it would save you a lot of trouble if you could just forget it exists.

Comment: No, as I mentioned .getElementsByClassName works fine in all browsers

Comment: @Cerebrus no support is required in ie11 for some customers

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a test with the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button class="fullscreen-button" onclick="abc()">Full screen</button>


<script>
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreen-button");
  x[0].click();

function abc()
{
 console.log("button clicked...");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

Comment: If you think that the above suggestion can help to fix your issue then I suggest you mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.