# In any case can i get all the elements with same ID in edge browser without using getElementByClassName or querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have tried to use this (I know that ID should not be the same, but it must not be different in IE):

```
document.getElementById("myid")
```

but it only give me one element, but I need to count the length of the elements which are 176. Do not ask me why; this is the requirement.

I have to let my project run for IE version 5 to 11 and Edge.

Comment: Poor style of code, just give every element to be selected the same class, that should work for Edge. Another suggestion is to use jquery, it also works with Edge.

Comment: class wount work with internet explorer below 9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript document.getElementsByClassName compatibility with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [getElementById() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [getElementsByClassName() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and [the querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) document, we can see that: The getElementById() method support IE5.5+, the getElementsByClassName() method support IE9+, and the querySelectorAll() method support IE8+.

To find multiple elements in the old IE browser, you could use the [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) or [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) method to find these elements.

The getElementsByName and getElementsByTagName method support IE5+.

please refer to the following sample code:

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="text" id="txtvalue" name="inputvalue" value="item 1" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="txtvalue" name="inputvalue" value="item 2" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="txtvalue" name="inputvalue" value="item 3" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="txtvalue" name="inputvalue" value="item 4" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="txtvalue" name="inputvalue" value="item 5" /><br />
</div>

<script> 
    var items = document.getElementsByName("inputvalue"); 
    console.log(items.length);  //output: 5
    var items2 = document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    console.log(items2.length); //output: 5
</script>
```

Comment: for some weird reasons i am only getting first two elements by writing this